# How to resume the fragments ? I have created four fragments -A,B,C,D on diffrent buttons im calling these fragments e.g

Tags: android, fragment

```
public void selectFrag(View view) {

        Fragment fr = null;
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.ivSize)) {

            fr = new SizeFragment();



        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.ivFrame)) {

            fr = new FramesFragment();

        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.ivMat)) {

            fr = new MatFragment();

        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.ivGlass)) {

            fr = new GlassTypeFragment();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("inside_width", insideWidth);
            bundle.putString("inside_height", insideHeight);
            // set Fragmentclass Arguments
            fr.setArguments(bundle);
       }

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

- every time i click on buttion new fragment is created.
  I have two resume my previous fragment on button click instead of creating new.

Answer (score 0):

Add your fragments to backstack and when you would like to show again one of them get it from the backstack.

Comment: can you please provide source code to pop up specific fragment from stack

Answer (score 0):

Just retain the instance and the onResume will be hit instead of onCreate.

```
    //MEMBER VARIABLES OF THE CLASS
    Fragment sizeFragment = new SizeFragment;

    Fragment framesFragment = new FramesFragment;

    Fragment matFragment = new MatFragment;

    Fragment glassTypeFragment = new GlassTypeFragment;

    Fragment selectedFragment = null

private void updateFragment(View view){
    if (view == findViewById(R.id.ivSize)) {
            selectedFragment = sizeFragment;
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.ivFrame)) {
            selectedFragment = framesFragment;
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.ivMat)) {
            selectedFragment = matFragment;
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.ivGlass)) {
            selectedFragment = glassTypeFragment;

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("inside_width", insideWidth);
            bundle.putString("inside_height", insideHeight);
            // set Fragmentclass Arguments
            fr.setArguments(bundle);
       }

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I think it's also worth mentioning that doing a findById each time to compare which fragment to show is a bit heavy in searching xml, I'm sure you can find a better architecture to know which one should be showing, but maybe I'm wrong.

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding.